# Adobe air loading progress bar at initialization

Tags: apache-flex, air

I am trying to make the application window (Adobe Air) show up quickly with a loading progress bar until all the components of the windowedApplication are loaded. What I trying to do is something very similar to what Adobe does for Flex by default, but strangely doesn't for Air.

What I trying to escape the "blank 15 second wait time" that my application takes to start after it is executed. Basically, if there is no preloader, it just is very confusing to the user as no visual response (windows etc) after clicking on the application icon might result in the user trying to open it up twice/thrice more times. I just want something which keeps the user busy with a preloader/splash screen.

Something similar is posted on Adobe's website:- http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=layoutperformance_07.html#172599

I looked at answers to [Adobe AIR - Custom Preloader with Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917667/adobe-air-custom-preloader-with-image)

*However*, that causes the following problem to which I haven't found a solution in the past 15 days:-

[User Login validation and preloader in Adobe Air](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990780/user-login-validation-and-preloader-in-adobe-air)

**Sample Project**
You can download the sample project following the link to the file of my dropbox account:-
https://www.dropbox.com/s/n43hdsmil6ox6js/preloader.fxp

The project can be opened in Flash builder (I used SDK 4.6, so you might have to change the application descriptor in case you are compiling/running on a different sdk version) and run it to get a login screen.. Login with

**user/password**

*and then notice how the UI/application window becomes unresponsive and stops responding for 5-10 seconds*.. Even Alt+Tab to the window won't work!

It basically does not have any logical data within - I just made sure to have a lot of UI components so as to increase the UI creation time.

What I am trying to do instead is for the application window to continue to respond and have a progress/loading message in a modal dialog

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the issue correctly, it sounds like what you need is to build a [Modular Application](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f22.html). The idea is that you put as little code/assets in the main application as possible, and simply use it as an entry point to the rest of your code. The link I provided should cover all the details, but here is the basic idea:

*MyApplication.mxml*

```
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function login_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                trace("login_clickHandler(event)");

                this.moduleLoader.url = "MyModule.swf";
                this.moduleLoader.loadModule();

                this.currentState = "loading";

            }

            protected function moduleLoader_updateCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                trace("moduleLoader_updateCompleteHandler(event)");

                this.moduleLoader.removeEventListener(FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE, moduleLoader_updateCompleteHandler);
                this.currentState = "ready";
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="login" />
        <s:State name="loading" />
        <s:State name="ready" />
    </s:states>

    <s:ModuleLoader id="moduleLoader" top="0" left="0" bottom="0" right="0"
                    updateComplete="moduleLoader_updateCompleteHandler(event)" />

    <s:Button label="Login" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" includeIn="login" click="login_clickHandler(event)" />

    <mx:ProgressBar id="progressBar" source="{this.moduleLoader}" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"
                    includeIn="loading" />

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

*MyModule.mxml*

```
<s:Module xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" width="100%" height="100%"
          creationComplete="module1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            /**
             * Let's embed a video to simulate load time..
             */
            [Embed(source = "VID_20130603_212046.mp4", mimeType = "audio/mpeg")]
            private static const VIDEO_SOURCE:Class;

            protected function module1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                trace("MyModule.module1_creationCompleteHandler(event)");

            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Panel top="40" left="40" bottom="40" right="40">

        <s:Label text="Hello World" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" />

    </s:Panel>

</s:Module>
```

This will keep the startup time for the main application window down to a minimum, and give you an entry point prior to loading up all the heavy resources.

**UPDATE**

After looking at the example project in your update, you simply need to set creationPolicy="auto" in your ViewStack, rather than "all." Setting it to all will attempt to instantiate every single view in the stack within a single update, which is almost guaranteed to lock the thread.

Most likely this will be sufficient for your use case, without having to mess around with modules.

Comment: ok.. i can figure out that the progress bar shows up with the loading state. How do we transition to the next state 'ready' and view MyModule? The ModuleLoader's update complete event will be fired right away, even when the button to login has not been clicked as the component is included in the view/state.

Comment: I've added a link to the sample project and have updated the question which explains the issue more clearly.. Please see if you can figure a way out

Comment: I had intentionally set the creationPolicy to all because I wanted all of the UI to be created at startup. If I have it set as auto/none, the application behaves unresponsive each time I am to change the view (while instantiation of a new viewnavigator node)

Comment: @Rohan You are simply trying to create to much at once through MXML. This is a common pitfall, and why Flex gets a bad rep for being sluggish. You need to manage your view creation more carefully, so as not to create more than is needed at any given time (this includes over-dependence on nested MXML tags). If there is simply no way around it in your situation, you can use something like pseudo-threading to prevent a greedy update cycle from locking the thread: http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2008/01/threads_in_actionscript_3.html

Comment: PS: Another strategy that would probably work well for you is to defer creation of child components until the next update cycle, using something like callLater after the creationComplete event on the parent container. Basically, create the child view in phases so no single update cycle gets to greedy.